# Whitelisting request/response headers with nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I am configuring a reverse proxy in nginx using `proxy_pass`.  I am then using `proxy_set_header` to override certain request headers and `proxy_hide_header` to remove certain response headers.

This effectively creates a blacklist of headers that I do not want to pass through my proxy.

Ideally, though, I would want to define a whitelist of headers that *are* allowed to pass through.  For example, I might want to hide all headers except `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` (and a few others, probably).

Is there any mechanism in nginx to implement this sort of header whitelist while proxying?  I can't seem to find this in this nginx documentation or through Google searches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [openresty/headers-more-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) on github. Seems to fit your needs quite well.

Comment: It's ideal for that. You have to build Nginx with that module in it, I have instructions for that here https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source